# Best jQuery practice for setting events on HTML from Ajax responses

Tags: jquery, ajax, binding

(Sorry, too long, mmmv!)  I'm new to jQuery (via Rails 3), and have a general best-practice question...

I have a link which toggles a div, hiding or showing and filling it (with the xhr.responseText) via the ajax:beforeSend and ajax:success bindings, respectively.
The responseText is HTML: a few forms for existing email addresses and a link to create a new email address.
Clicking the new link loads a blank email address form via Ajax at the top of the div opened via the toggle above.

I want the first field in the new email address form to receive focus, and to do it unobtrusively via jQuery, I've needed to trigger a custom event in the original toggle's ajax:success binding and have the custom event bind the focusing code to the new links.

After reading about .live, .delegate, and .on, I had thought jQuery might match and operate on new content added to the page via Ajax (ie: "now and in the future") a bit more simply and my approach, while working, seems brittle and tightly-coupled.

I have more behavior for HTML content returned via Ajax to wire-up and am curious if I'm missing something and there is a much better way?

Code below for reference, thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.shows-children').bind('ajax:beforeSend', function(evnt, xhr, settings){

        var boxSelector = '#' + $(this).data("shows");

        if($(boxSelector).is(':visible')){
            $(boxSelector).fadeOut(function(){
                $(this).empty();
            });
            return false;
        } else {
            $(boxSelector).fadeIn();
        }
    });

    $('.shows-children').bind('ajax:success', function(evnt, data, status, xhr){
        var boxSelector = '#' + $(this).data("shows");

        $(boxSelector).html(xhr.responseText);
        $('a.new').trigger('set_bindings_for_new_links');
    });

});


$(document).on('set_bindings_for_new_links', function(){
    $('a.new').bind('ajax:success', function(evnt, data, status, xhr){
        $(this).parent().find('form[id^="new_"] :input:visible:first').focus();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah yeah...

1) http://docs.jquery.com/FAQ#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F

2) http://www.learningjquery.com/2008/05/working-with-events-part-2